# I am not able to get back selected recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel

I am using two fragments in an activity, with the first fragment having Recyclerview.

In portrait mode it is showing the first fragment only and on rotation both fragments are showing

The issue is with the recyclerview items going to blank while rotating the screen.

I am using view model but it's not retaining the recyclerview state.

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Did you used LiveData to observe data changes?

Comment: Can you please share some of your code?